# install4j 6.1.1 Linux installer issue that worked in 6.0.3

Tags: install4j

I have my installer set up so that if the installer is run in the terminal/cmd with a parameter, it runs a script in the 'Finish' section after installation that uses a class and a resource from my main program jar.  The code in the class uses obj.getClass().getResourceAsStream('relative path') to get the resource.

This worked in install4j 6.0.3.  In 6.1.1 it still works in the windows installer, but in my linux installer, the code will run but it can't find the necessary resource.

Any advice?  Let me know if I need to clarify more, in my head it sounds like all the necessary information, I'm not so great at abstracting myself from the situation.

Comment: To check where a class is loaded from, try to print getClass().getResource()

Comment: That's how I noticed that was the issue, putting a print there, it returns null.  I did however today get the println into a version 5 install4j, and it returns the temp installation directory/user/mycodejar/resource relative path.  Which is about what I expected.

Comment: and getClass().getResource("ClassName.class") where ClassName is the simple name of the class?

Comment: Both in the old install and the new one it returned null, but this inspired me to change what I was doing a little, the code just used a generic object to call get class, and I changed it to using the specific class and that worked.  Looks like it was a difference in class loaders that made the difference.  Thanks for the suggestions, they definitely inspired me :)